# cannot ensure the windows explorer popup is in foreground

Tags: selenium, jenkins, popupwindow

I have a selenium webdriver test application written in java. As part of the web application a button click will open a popup "windows explorer" to select folder for upload. The problem is my java selenium application works well when I run from a command window. but when this application is run from jenkins the popup
window is not always in the foremost so the folder upload fails.

```
        StringSelection strSelection = new StringSelection(path);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(strSelection, null);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Robot robot;
            robot = new Robot();
            // Press CTRL+V
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
....
```

Answer (score 0):

use a vbscript to minimize all windows before the mvn initiation in jenkins. this will ensure popup is in foreground
set oShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

```
 oShellApp.MinimizeAll
```